# I am trying to pass Blob object to php file using AJAX but failed to do so

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to upload Blob Object to php file using XMLHttpRequest(); but Blob is not passing to the php file.

```
    blob_it = new Blob(array_of_blobs);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","page.php",true);
    xhr.send("blob_object="+blob_it);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    }
```

On 'page.php' script looks like

```
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['blob_object']) === true){
                    echo "Object received";
                }else{
                    echo "No object received";
                }
                ?>
```

It returns 'No object received'. I think something is missing in my AJAX request. Please can any one tell.

Comment: how does your xhr request body look like?

Comment: I'd suggest using `FormData` to pass a binary data. I've also removed your `jquery` tag as it's not relevant to the code you posted, and I replaced it with  `javasscript`

Comment: @madalinivascu xhr body contains only simple Blob Object. thats it